# const & (ref) used in template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have seen in some code the following :

```
template<const Foo& bar>
```

I was told its purpose was to handle big structures.

Can't we then use const & directly in the code non-templatized arguments ?
Can it be considered a good practice to pass object references around as arguments using a const reference as template parameter ?

Comment: Your question is vague as the origin of the universe. What is the context of this code? Non-type template parameters of reference type are really rare and obscure.

Comment: Reading between the huge gaps in the lines he might be asking whether it's good practice to pass object references around as arguments using a const reference where possible and the answer to that is: "yes it is".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [non-type template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments), which happens to be of type `const Foo&`.

Whatever its use there is ("big structures" isn't really *that* descriptive), like all non-type template parameters its advantage is to be usable at compile-time (for example in metaprograms), its drawback is that you *must* have its value at compile-time. It being a compile-time constant *may* also help the compiler optimize it better.

Here are some examples :

```
struct Foo {};

/////////////////////////////////
// Type template parameter :
template <class T>
struct TypeParame {
    T const &tRef; // T is a type
};

/////////////////////////////////
// Non-type template parameters :

// Integral type
template <int I>
struct NonTypeParam {
    // I is a value
    enum { constant = I };
};

// Reference
template <Foo const &F>
struct RefParam {
    // F is a value again
    Foo const &ref = F;
};

// Pointer
template <Foo const *F>
struct PtrParam {
    // F is still a value
    Foo const *ptr = F;
};

// More are possible, but...

// error: 'struct Foo' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
template <Foo F>
struct ValParam {};
```

Comment: Thank you Quentin in your link I can see `template<const Y& b> struct Z {};` which correspond to what I have seen sometimes. Can't we have an equivalent with `template<Y b>` and use the reference elsewhere ?

Comment: @coincoin You may be mixing it up with *type* template parameters, where declaring `template <class T>` will enable you to then decorate `T` however you want (e.g `T&`). With *non*-type template parameters though, the parameter is the *value*. So, no.

Comment: @coincoin see my edit fo hopefully clearer examples.